# How to update table in sqlite android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

In my app i want to update my database table based on two column.Means update salary where `firstname="ekant"` and `last name="kancha"`.So can any body plz tell me what will be the query i have to write.

```
public int updateStatus(int salary,String fname,String lName)
{
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    String where = fname+ "=" + "ekanta";
    cv.put("salary",salary);
    return sdb.update(DATABASE_TABLENAME, cv, where, null);

}
```

this code works only when i want to update based on first name..But i want to update based on firstname and lastname.

plz help me.thanx

Comment: Try this: `String where = fname+ "=" + "ekanta" + " AND " + lname+"=" +"lastName";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this...

```
 String where = fname+ "=" + "ekanta" + " and " + lname + "=" + "your lastname";
```

Comment: Besides resulting in invalid SQL, this is too hard to read and too easy to break.

Comment: Actually I was just seeing his code and he said ( String where = fname+ "=" + "ekanta";) is working. So I just told about lastname. Obviously you answer is the best.

Comment: I'm surprised that "somefirstname=ekanta and.." is even valid.

Answer (score 5):

Use *placeholders*. This makes it easier to *read* the SQL query and protects against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (accidental or otherwise).

```java
public int updateSalary (int salary, String fname, String lName)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("salary", salary);

                 /* use COLUMN NAMES here */                     
    String where = "firstname = ? and lastname = ?";
                 /* bind VALUES here */
    String[] whereArgs = new { fname, lname };
    return sdb.update(DATABASE_TABLENAME, cv, where, whereArgs);
}
```

If you have constants (e.g. `private final static COLUMN_FNAME = "firstname"`) for the COLUMN NAMES, then you can build `where` using these constants.

However, *do not put VALUES* in the `where` string. Instead, use `?` and supply any VALUES via the `whereArgs` array as per the above example.

---

Also, it is possible for people (even within the same organization) to share the same first name and last name. Basing the database queries/updates around such a pairing will *break* in such cases so it may be prudent to work on designing the API to work with a better record identifier.